# If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x^2)=a$ (a finite number), then which of the following is/are true?

Tags: calculus, limits, contest-math

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x^2)=a$ (a finite number), then which of the following is/are true?

A) $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2f'(x^2)=0$

B) $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2f'(x^2)=2a$

C) $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^4f''(x^2)=0$

D) $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^4f''(x^2)=a$

In [this video solution](https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer/if-limx-rarr-oo-fx2-a-a-finite-nubmer-then-which-of-the-following-is-are-true-1577194), they have taken the example of a function which satisfies the given limit and then commented about each option.

Is there any general way to solve this question without using delta-epsilon method?

Comment: Since $f$ is not given to be differentiable, the answer is trivial. All the options are false.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes, it's not mentioned in the question that f is differentiable. But maybe we can just assume that, to answer the options.

Comment: Even if $f$ has continuous derivatives all the options are false. The hypothesis does not lead to any conclusion about the behavior of derivatives of $f$ at $\infty$.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks. In that video solution, they took $f(x)=\frac{ax}{x+1}$. It would be great if you can add some comment about it.

Comment: You can substitute $t=x^2.$  For $f(t)=a+{1\over t}\sin(t^2)$ I believe none of the $4$ conditions is satisfied.